# Simple VueJS issue (setting $data in mounted)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

## Edit

The Component.vue provided was part of a larger web app so I ripped out the relevant code for this question. What I didn't notice was a VERY tiny change I made in ripping out the code that had a very big impact.

There's a difference between:

```
mounted() {
    // ....
}
```

and:

```
mounted: () => {
    // ....
}
```

Upon careful investigation this morning I found this mistake in my code and I've updated the question to reflect the actual code that was failing.

## Question

I may just be tired, but before going to bed I wanted to ask for help here and see if someone can find my issue. I have a very simple Vue component that isn't working:

Component.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p v-for="item in items">{{ item.text }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                items: []
            };
        },
        mounted: () => {
            var _this = this;
            $.ajax("/items.json").done(result => {
                _this.items = result;
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

items.json

```
[
    {"text": "ABC"},
    {"text": "XYZ"}
]
```

The paragraphs are never rendering. Upon inspection it looks like `_this.items` doesn't exist prior to setting it in the AJAX handler (I expect it to be an empty array) and `_this.$data` also doesn't exist

~Is the value of `this` different in the mounted method than elsewhere in Vue?~ **Or did I make a simple mistake?**

Writing the `mounted` function in this way (with the colon) causes the value of `this` to be different. Why is that?

Comment: It should work, but since you're using an arrow function in the `done`, reassigning `this` isn't necessary. Try it without.

Comment: It works for me in a snippet where I use `setTimeout` instead of `$.ajax`.

Comment: Try switching `$.ajax` to `$.getJSON`. Perhaps your server isn't delivering the `items.json` file with the correct `Content-type` and jQuery is unable to determine the data type automatically. Also, how are you opening your app; via `http://` or `file:///`?

Comment: @stevendesu, I think the code is fine. You should check if `/items.json` accessible. This could be your web server setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Upon further research, I have learned of the subtle difference between normal functions and arrow functions. I previously thought the latter was just a short-hand, but it also does not have its own context.

The method `mounted: () => {}` utilizes an arrow function, and therefore

> ...does not have its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Here is a simple example demonstrating the difference which can be tested in the Chrome console

```
let testFunc = function() { console.log(this); }
testFunc(); // Window {...}
testFunc.bind("test")(); // String {"test"}
testFunc = () => { console.log(this); }
testFunc(); // Window {...}
testFunc.bind("test")(); // Window {...}
```

When utilizing an arrow function, it becomes impossible to bind a value to `this`. This means that in the Vue internals they are unable to bind the Vue instance to `this`.

The method `mounted() { }` is only utilizing the ES6 short-hand for objects, and not an arrow function (therefore it **does** have its own context and you **can** bind the `this` variable)

Answer (score 2):

Mounting hooks are often the most-used hooks, for better or worse. They allow you to access your component immediately before and after the first render. They do not, however, run during server-side rendering.

Use if: You need to access or modify the DOM of your component immediately before or after the initial render.

Do not use if: You need to fetch some data for your component on initialization. Use created() (or created + activated for keep-alive components) for this instead, especially if you need that data during server-side rendering.

So try to change mounted() to created() and see if it works. Also, I suggest you look at axios to send request which is a better alternative to $.ajax(). Make sure you are requesting the json file from the right path.